# mathematical statistics written by Jun Shao P29

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

For a symmetric  $k\times k$ matrix $M$, let $R_M = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^k:y = Mx \text{ with some }x \in R^k\}$ . If a random $k$-vector $X$ has a finite $\operatorname{Var}(X)$, then $P(X-EX \in R_{\operatorname{Var}(X)})=1$.

How to understand this?

Answer (score 0):

Idea: let $z \in R_{\operatorname{Var}(X)}^\perp$, i.e. $z\cdot y = 0$ for all $y\in R_{\operatorname{Var}(X)}$. Then $$\operatorname{var}(z\cdot X) = \mathrm E\bigl(z^\top (X-\mathrm E X)(X-\mathrm E X)^\top z\bigr) = z^\top \operatorname{Var}(X) z = z\cdot (\operatorname{Var}(X) z) = 0,$$
whence $\mathrm P(z\cdot X = 0)=1$.

Comment: and why Var(X) is finite? from your procedure, the infinite I think can go through. Thank you!

Comment: The finiteness (more accurately, existence) is assumed in your question.